# How can I maximize the binomial random variable

Tags: probability

$X$ is binomial random variable. I want to find values of $j$ for which

$$ f(j) = P(X = j ) = \frac{ n!}{(n-j)!j!} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}$$

is maximum. I was given the hint to calculate $\frac{ f(j+1)}{f(j)} $, which I calculate and is

$$ \frac{j + 1}{np - p^2n - jp + jp^2 } $$

But, I am stuck how can I use this information to find the maximum.

Comment: Please revise your computation of the ratio f(j+1)/f(j).

Comment: Why is it true that when $F(j)$ is maximum, then the ratio is less than $1$ ?

Comment: When $f(j)$ is maximum, $f(j + 1) \le f(j) \implies \frac {f(j + 1)}{f(j)} \le 1$. Now, solve for $j$ in terms of $n$ and $p$ (I didn't check if your computed expression is correct).

Comment: I think it's because if $f(j)$ is maximum, then when we evaluate $f$ at any other value, say $k$, $f(k)$ cannot be greater than the maximum i.e. $f(j)$. In particular, $f(j + 1) \le f(j)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, observe that $$\begin{align*}\frac{f(j+1)}{f(j)} &= \frac{\frac{ n!}{(n-j-1)!(j+1)!} p^{j+1} (1-p)^{n-j-1}}{\frac{ n!}{(n-j)!j!} p^j (1-p)^{n-j}}\\\\&=\frac{n!(n-j)(n-j-1)!j!p^jp(1-p)^{n-j}(1-p)^{-1}}{n!(n-j-1)!(j+1)j!p^j(1-p)^{n-j}}=\frac{(n-j)p}{(j+1)(1-p)}\end{align*}$$ Now, using that $f(j)$ increases in $j$ until it reaches a maximum and then it decreases (perhaps you need to prove this), you can solve the equation $$f(j+1)\le f(j) \iff \frac{f(j+1)}{f(j)}\le 1$$ to obtain that $$j\ge (n+1)p-1=E[X]+p-1$$ So the maximum is obtained at $j_0$ which is given by $$j_0=\lceil E[X]+p-1 \rceil$$ where $\lceil \rceil$ denotes the ceiling function.

Comment: How can I prove that ()  increases in  until it reaches a maximum and then it decreases? I see that $f(j)=f(n-j)$ but not much more.

Comment: @JKEG For $j<j_0$, you have that $f(j+1)>f(j)$ meaning that $f$ is strictly increasing in this interval and for $j>j_0$, you have the opposite, i.e., that $f(j+1)<f_j $ meaning that $f$ is strictly decreasing in this interval. So, at $j_0$ you get a unique max (modulo ceiling rounding). There are no other changes above/below 1 of this ratio.